# Select last cell in a column with blanks

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to find the last cell in a column that is populated with data in VBA.  The problem is, in the range, there are blank cells.  Is there any way to select the last cell with data if there are blanks? Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have pasted my range definitions below.

```
If Range("BL2") <> "" Or Range("BM2") <> "" Then
                            Set usr11 = Range("BL:BL")
                            Set usr12 = Range("BM:BM")
```

Comment: the question is not precise enough about wich column you want tofind the last row, "BL" or "BM" , or both ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Find

This will work on the ActiveSheet

```
Dim lngLastRow as Long

'If column is A
lngLastRow = Columns(1).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Comment: Could I do usr11.Cells instead of ActiveSheet or would that not work?

Comment: The range variable usr11 can be substituted for Columns(1)

Comment: @Philip Columns is also the columns of Activesheet. Your Range is a Columns range. So : Range("BL:BL") = Columns("BL:BL") = Columns("BL") = Columns(64) . For your information Excel convert index numerique or letters because it use also L1R1 system notation

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for

This is what I use to get the last row; just give it a column and a sheet.

```
Function getLastRow(sheet As String, Col As Variant) As Integer
    getLastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Sheets(sheet).Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).row
End Function
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Range("A" & getLastRow(ActiveSheet,"A")).Select 'Select the last row in column A
```

Similar function to get the last column with data:

```
Function getLastCol(sheet As String, row As Variant) As Integer
    getLastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, Sheets(sheet).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

Comment: that work if you work on ThisWorkbook but with addin... or other global workbool function you don't get a good result.

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you

```
Sub SelectBlank()
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'change to whatever column you have
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
            Range("A" & i).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```