# Finding the number of non empty cells and paste copied data just after

Tags: vba, excel

i write a sub to find the number of non empty cells :

```
Sub test()

        Dim i, mynumber As Integer

        For i = 22 To 500
            If Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0 Then mynumber = mynumber + 1
        Next i

    End Sub
```

For example when I execute this code, i got mynumber=8, sometimes i got mynumber21, etc,...

I copied a data and i want to paste them two rows after the number of non empty cells (that is why I wrote this code).

I am stuck here.

Comment: You want to find the last row of data on the sheet (or column) or count the number of cells that do not contain data (which could be different from the last row containing data)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769061/select-last-cell-in-a-column-with-blanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the last row in the column you can use this code:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

And then just add two rows to the range for when you want to paste it.

Comment: @John you shouldn't need to loop through the rows anymore, as this code assigns LastRow as the number of the last row. So just add two to this number to give you the number where you want to paste your data.

Comment: how can i edit my code ? i dont understand. your code works fine, but i dont know how can i use it to paste my copied data.

Comment: For i = 22 To Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row